# Spartacus 4.2 - Type '"before"' is not assignable to type 'OutletPosition'

Tags: spartacus-storefront

While trying to customize the navigation slot, we are getting the error

> Type '"before"' is not assignable to type 'OutletPosition'.

This is the code we are trying.

[image]

Also have tried

`[cxOutletPos]=“outletPosition.BEFORE”`

Documentation referred for Spartacus 4.2 :

> https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/outlets/#template-driven-outlets

Result should be something like custom info, followed by navigation bar as shown below:

[image]

Also, as the above method didn't work I tried retrieving data through let-model for manipulation.
Array I want to retrieve data from into our component: CategoryNavigationComponent.
But using let-model and Printing model object I can see only "uid" , "typeCode" and "flexType" but not the navigatioNode and Children.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there any way to retrieve Navigation bar or Children array data on the screen?

Comment: Have you also tried using `[cxOutletRef]`?

Comment: @CaineRotherham we are using cxOutletRef to refer to the slot CategoryNavigationComponent which I want to customize. I am only receiving tabs from Home to Admin as showing in the reference image. I want to add the profile image, name and designation above it.

Comment: Are you importing OutletRefModule, as per the documentation?

Comment: @NeilHubert-Price yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
****in TS File:****
  settingsSubmenu: any = [];

constructor(public component: CmsComponentData<any> )
{
   this.component.data$.forEach(element => {
     element.navigationNode.children.forEach(child => {
      this.settingsSubmenu.push(child)   
     });
    });
}
**in HTML File**

 <ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of settingsSubmenu">
                        <a mat-menu-item >{{menuItem.title}}</a>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your questions is about Typescript error, then possible two solutions:

1. Modify *tsconfig.json* to ignore Typescript error:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "angularCompilerOptions": {
       ...
       "strictTemplates": false
     }
   }
   ```
2. Modify your code to compile without errors:

   In **.component.ts* file add import:

   ```
    import {OutletPosition} from '@spartacus/storefront';
   ```

   and define variable:

   ```
    outletPosition = OutletPosition;
   ```

   In **.component.html* file:

   ```
    [cxOutletPos]="outletPosition.BEFORE"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First you should import OutletPOsition in xxxxx.component.ts

import {OutletPosition } from '@spartacus/storefront';

then in the exportClass that Implement OnInit add

before: OutletPosition = OutletPosition.BEFORE;

finally you can use it in this way
<ng-template cxOutletRef="Section1" [cxOutletPos]="before" >